# perl + printing to file

Tags: perl

The following script print some characters.

how to print the characters to file ( for example /var/tmp/file )

Yael

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 


@myNames = ('one', 'two', 'three' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E');

foreach (@myNames) {

print "$_\n";

}
```

Comment: It appears that you are doing much more advanced Perl than this -- why ask such a question?  Your other questions, in particular your XML questions, would seem to require a better Perl understanding that this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 


@myNames = ('one', 'two', 'three' , 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'D' , 'E');

open(OUT,">","/var/tmp/file") or die "Could not open the output file: $!";

foreach (@myNames) {

print OUT "$_\n";

} 

close(OUT);
```

Comment: THX
in which cases we can get the "Could not open the output file"
Yael

Comment: One reason could be the target output file might be locked by some other process. In such cases, the program gets terminated with this error message

Comment: Use lexical filehandles, not globals.  And you are missing `use strict; use warnings;`.

Answer (score 2):

When you run the script, you can simply redirect the output to a file:

```
$ ./myscript.pl > /var/tmp/file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open(FILE, ">/var/tmp/file") || die "File not found";
print FILE @myNames;
close(FILE);
```

Comment: it wasn't me, but probably because you used a bareword file handle rather than a lexical, and you are not using the three argument open.  `open my $file, '>', '/var/tmp/file' or die "error opening file: $!";`

Comment: well, as long as this example is still in the official perldoc (Perl 5 version 12.1 documentation: http://perldoc.perl.org/ ), there is nothing wrong with it I think. So who ever is playing around with negative votes seems to be a know-it-all, that isn't able to read the official documentation.

Comment: It is a dumb example. "File not found" is a dumb error message. It's obvious that the file doesn't exist, or that it does exist but you don't care because you're going to wipe it out. Perhaps one or more of the leading directories does not exist, or you don't have permission to overwrite the file or write to the directory, or the file system is full, but we don't know what the problem is because you didn't include $! in the error message. All we know from this error is that we "Failed to create file", but the message doesn't even say that.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie qw(:all);

my @names = qw(one two three A B C D E);

{
    open my $fh, '>', '/var/tmp/file';
    foreach (@names) {
        print {$fh} "$_\n";
    }
}
```